# TypeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘__getitem__’

Tags: python

I am having an issue where I am simply trying to return if two values in two lists are the same, but I have getting the TypeError issue.

```
def check_cond_2(day_shifts, night_shifts, day):
    return day_shifts[day] == night_shifts[day]
```

TypeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘_*getitem*_’

I added a print statement with the condition before return to check if it’s the problem with the condition but it seems to print true or false as I expected, and all I need to do is to return that Boolean but it produces the error on the line of return statement.

Comment: No way to tell what's going on without knowing what you actually pass as `day_shifts` and `night_shifts`. (well, `None` obviously, but where does it come from)

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError` you're encountering is probably due to either `day_shifts` or `night_shifts` being `None`. The error message suggests that `None` does not have the `_getitem_` attribute, which is used to access elements using indexing. To resolve this, you should check if either `day_shifts` or `night_shifts` is `None` before attempting to access their elements.

```
def check_cond_2(day_shifts, night_shifts, day):
    if day_shifts is None or night_shifts is None:
        return False
    else:
        return day_shifts[day] == night_shifts[day]
```